# How to compress a simple shell script onto one line?

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh

a friend of mine made this super cool shell script that I want to convert into one line of code. After converting it and executing it, I noticed it wasn't working as it was meant to. There are no errors weirdly enough, what have I done wrong. Here is the code from before and after.

Before

```
folders=(hydra1)
num=1
while :
do
for i in ${folders[@]}
do
if [ ! -d $i ]
then
mkdir $i
mkdir hydra$num
folders+=(hydra$num)
((num++))
fi
done
sleep 0.1
done
```

after

```
while :; do for i in ${folders[@]}; do if [ ! -d $i ]; then mkdir $i; mkdir hydra$num; folders+=(hydra$num); ((num++)); fi; done; sleep 0.1; done
```

By the way, if you want to know what it does, it's a small virus that make folders that duplicate themselves when you delete them. It's better if you run it on your desktop.

Comment: _"shell script that I want to convert into one line of code"_ -- umm, why? You'll just make it harder to read, understand and edit. So don't. Rather fix the indentation in the original.

Comment: That `folders=(hydra1)` `mkdir $i; mkdir hydra$num; folders+=(hydra$num)` doesn't make much sense either. It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization of the variables was left out. if `${folders[@]}` is empty, the for loop is never entered.

Comment: Also, multiple instances of unquoted variable expansions, and no handling of errors. But that was in the original too.

Comment: Oh shoot your right! I completely forgot to add the vars at the start! My bad!

Comment: @Kusalananda, OP used the `zsh` tag (though also bash!?) so quoting may not be strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
folders=(hydra1); num=1; while :; do for i in ${folders[@]}; do if [ ! -d $i ]; then mkdir $i; mkdir hydra$num; folders+=(hydra$num); ((num++)); fi; done; sleep 0.1; done
```

Comment: Very tempting but no, I don't want to see this executing, not even on my tmpfs. If this is meant to be a prank that you can start on a colleague's computer while he is getting coffee, you might want to shorten it. mkdir for instance takes multiple paths, and and option not to object to existing paths. So you could throw the whole folders array to it at once.